# amcharts show a dynamic title when loading data using dataLoader

Tags: amcharts

I am using amcharts (MapArea within DataLoader) to fetch data as json and render the map. However, I also want to send a dynamic title/subtitle in json (e.g. Total Population: X), which I'd want to render in the Map. Is it possible? I couldn't find the correct property to send it in, in https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapArea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the map title, the dataLoader doesn't allow you to set the title directly as it only loads the [mapData properties](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapData) in the `dataProvider` (areas, lines, map type). You can store extra data in your JSON and use the dataLoader's `complete` callback to assign what you want to the chart instance itself.

For example, if you set a custom `title` property in your JSON response like so:

```
{
    "map": "/* your map here */",
    "title": "Your title text here",
    // other properties omitted
}
```

You can add that title text in the `complete` callback like so:

```
"dataLoader": {
  "url": "/* your json endpoint */",
  "complete": function(map) {
    map.addTitle(map.dataProvider.title);
  }
},
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/d330a5475c3b79d2e770f33fcba579d4?editors=0010)